# KornShell Script Comparison of Averages

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I'm trying to get this KornShell (ksh) to work, but the if statement seems to not be working (I certainly could be wrong).

```
Total=`echo ${marks[1]}+${marks[2]}+${marks[3]}+${marks[4]}+${marks[5]} | bc`
    Average=`echo "$Total  5" | awk '{print $1 / $2}'`

    if [ "$Average" -le "11.5" ]; then 
        result="failing"
    else 
        result="passing"
    fi

    print "Total: $Total"
    print "Result: $Average"
    print "$result"
```

Whenever I run it, the average and total are calculated correctly, but the result is always "failing" regardless of whether or not the average is < 11.5.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If ksh has a `[` builtin which recognizes floating point values, I would be surprised.  `[` typically only does arithmetic with integers

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly declare ksh variables for implicit conversion:

```
integer total_i
integer average_i

Total=`echo ${marks[1]}+${marks[2]}+${marks[3]}+${marks[4]}+${marks[5]} | bc`
Average=`echo "$Total  5" | awk '{print $1 / $2}'`

total_i = $Total
average_i = $Average

if [ average_i -le 11.5 ]; then 
    result="failing"
else 
    result="passing"
fi

print "Total: $Total"
print "Result: $Average"
print "$result"
```

Even though the variables are **integer** they can accommodate decimal values.